# GABA in plants (article about its mechanism)

Tags: plant-physiology, literature

I am studing to plant physiology exam and i cross over the statment about GABA in plants.

It said that level of GABA increasing my thermal shock. But mechanism of effect on plants is unknown.

Can anybody give me a tipe about proper article about it?

Comment: I am sorry for not doing my research part but i am quite busy.

Comment: Your comment perfectly nails down the main issue with your post. Respectfully, we are not here to do your work. Wether you are busy or not is irrelevant. We are all busy people and we would all be very pleased to have someone to work for us for free. I am VTC as homework question lacking effort. Good luck!

Comment: Unlike in Europe, in the US and Canada, there is actually loads of homework at the University. I dunno about other continents.